# Timer not showing left 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

Have a timer that I want to display as such: 00:00:00

However, sometime my timer displays this: 00:1:9.

Any advice on how to stop this?

Here is the code:

```
-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer;{

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSInteger secondsLeft = timeInterval;

        hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;


    _myCounterLabel.text =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%f interval", timeInterval);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you have a negative time interval. The `%02d` would print `-1` as `-1`. Then you replace the `-` with the empty string which leaves you with `1` instead of the expected `01`.

I'm not sure why you are replacing individual negative signs in the resulting string instead of properly handling a negative value for `secondsLeft`.

And a side note: There is no need for the double modulus calculation for `seconds`.

Try something like this:

```
-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer;{
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
    // Don't allow negative intervals
    NSInteger secondsLeft = timeInterval >= 0 ? timeInterval : 0;

    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = secondsLeft % 60;

    _myCounterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@"%f interval", timeInterval);
}
```